# For Loop to sample from a different list based on condition

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, sample

I have data that looks like this:

```
List_of_lists = list("0" = list(4,6), "1" = list(6,8), "2" = list(7,9), 
                     "3" = list(4,8), "4" = list(3,9,0), "6" = list(1,7,0), 
                     "7" = list(2,6), "8" = list(1,3), "9" = list(2,4))
```

I'd like to write an iterative function that first samples from the first index of `List_of_Moves` (i.e. "0"), and for subsequent iterations, sample from a different list whose name matches with the previous iteration's result. In other words, if the first iteration's result is a 4, then I sample from the list whose name is "4" - and so on and so forth.

In "Hack-n-Slash" R form, it looks something like this:

```
> sample(unlist(List_of_lists"0",1,replace=TRUE)
4
> sample(unlist(List_of_lists"4",1,replace=TRUE)
3
> sample(unlist(List_of_lists"3",1,replace=TRUE)
8
> sample(unlist(List_of_lists"8",1,replace=TRUE)
1
> sample(unlist(List_of_lists"1",1,replace=TRUE)
6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly something like this. We sample an element from the `List_of_lists`, store it as the result and pass it as initial parameter to the next round and at same time decrease the size by `1` until we meet the `size` criterial where we return `NULL` and the iteration stops:

```
r_ge <- function(init = "0", size) {
    if(size == 0) NULL
    else {
        tmp <- sample(List_of_lists[[as.character(init)]], 1)
        c(unlist(tmp), r_ge(tmp, size - 1))
    }
}
```

Use cases:

```
r_ge(size = 5)
# [1] 4 9 2 9 2
r_ge(size = 5)
# [1] 6 1 8 1 6
r_ge(size = 5)
# [1] 6 0 4 9 4
r_ge(size = 5)
# [1] 4 9 4 0 4
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean. The number of iterations is the size parameter you passed in and the total sum can be calculated after the iteration like `sum(r_ge(size = 5))`.

Comment: If you mean replicate it for 1000 times, you can calculate the average from the output like `mean(replicate(1000, r_ge(size = 5)))`.

Comment: What this function does is return back a sample of specific size just like all other functions, the result can be handled just like other functions like `sample` or `rnorm` for example.

Comment: I particularly liked the way you return the result from the recursive function.

Comment: For the threshold condition in the recursive function, if you just put `return(NULL)`, you won't need that `else` condition.

Comment: @m0h3n Thanks! That makes sense. Seems to be a nicer option.

Comment: It has something to do with the limit which R sets for nested expression. Increasing the parameter expression in the options function should work . `options(expression = 50000)` works for size = 1000.

Comment: Yes. Does it cause a stack overflow?

Comment: Well. If you keep increasing the number of iterations, it will break at some point eventually. But look at `?options`, the maximum value of `expression` is 500000, if you want to push it to the limit.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, I believe this also does what you what:

```
first_seed <- rbinom(n = 1, size = 9, prob = .5) # just to get a starting value
for (i in 1:20){
  first_seed <- sample(x = unlist(List_of_lists[[as.character(first_seed)]][]), 1)
  print(first_seed)
}
```

A few notes: `rbinom()` isn't perfect for getting the first value, but I leave that to you to modify. Also, the 1:20 is just for demonstration purposes, obviously increase or decrease the number of iterations as desired.